# PowerShell command in batch script condition

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I need a line of script that does something like this:

`if (results from PowerShell command not empty) do something`

The PowerShell command is basically

`powershell -command "GetInstalledFoo"`

I tried `if (powershell -command "GetInstalledFoo" != "") echo "yes"` but get the error `-command was unexpected at this time.` Is this possible to accomplish? This command will eventually be run as the command to `cmd /k`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BartekB's answer works as long as at least one line of output does not start with the FOR /F eol character (defaults to `;`) and does not consist entirely of delimiter characters (defaults to space and tab). With appropriate FOR /F options it can be made to always work.

But here is a simpler (and I believe faster) way to handle multiple lines of output that should always work.

```
for /f %%A in ('powershell -noprofile -command gwmi win32_process ^| find /v /c ""') do if %%A gtr 0 echo yes
```

Another alternative is to use a temp file.

```
powershell -noprofile -command gwmi win32_process >temp.txt
for %%F in (temp.txt) if %%~zF gtr 0 echo yes
del temp.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Third way: set an environment variable from your PowerShell script and test it in your batch file?

Answer (score 1):

I guess if won't be the best solution for that. I would use `for /f` instead:

```
for /f %R in ('powershell -noprofile -command echo foo') do @echo bar
```

That should give you 'bar', while this:

```
for /f %R in ('powershell -noprofile -command $null') do @echo bar
```

... should not. In actual .bat/ .cmd file you have to double % (%%R)

or better yet, if you don't want to many bar's returned...:

```
(for /f %R in ('powershell -noprofile -command gwmi win32_process') do @echo bar) | find "bar" > nul && echo worked
```